# How to get all emitted values from different EventEmitter at the same time in the Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-event-emitter

I have a parent component, and parent component have multiple child component. 
And each child may be different component. For example;

```
                          --- Parent ---
                                |
 Child1(component1) --- Child2(component1) --- Child3(component5) .....
```

I want that when I click the button in the `parent` component, I want to get messages from the all `child` components at the same time. I'm able to use `EventEmitter` to get value from child to parent, but I don't know how to get all child values at the same time?

**Edit:**

My child components are created dynamically like this;

```
@ViewChild('component1Container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) component1ContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild('component2Container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) component2ContainerRed: ViewContainerRef;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your components by ids inside the parent template:

```js
@Component({selector: 'parent', template: `
  <app-child1 #child1>
  <app-child2 #child2>
  <app-child3 #child3>
  <button (click)="onButtonClick(child1.aProp, child2.anotherProp, child3.thirdProp)"></button>
`})
class ParentComponent {
  onButtonClick(aProp: string, anotherProp: number, thirdProp: string): void { ... }
}
```

---

Or, you can use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) directive to direct access children components inside the parent component, like this:

```js
@Component({selector: 'parent', template: `
  <app-child1 #child1>
  <app-child2 #child2>
  <app-child3 #child3>
  <button (click)="onButtonClick()"
`})
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild("child1", {static: false}) child1!: Child1Component;
  @ViewChild("child2", {static: false}) child2!: Child2Component;
  @ViewChild("child3", {static: false}) child3!: Child3Component;

  onButtonClick(): void {
   console.log(this.child1.aProp, this.child2.anotherProp, this.child3.thirdProp);
  }
}
```